# Status of machine code generation in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Recently I've been looking into LLVM as a back-end for a compiler project, which looks very promising.

However, it seems that LLVM can JIT code (which is very cool!) or it can export assembly for the native platform, but it can't actually create native executables.  This seems like a major limitation for the compiler back-end infrastructure that LLVM claims to be.

I'm working on a project where I'd like the compiled executables to be able to run without LLVM installed (i.e. no JIT).  Does LLVM have any native assemblers that can be used to generate machine code (not LLVM bitcode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM (by means of the MC library you've mentioned) can generate *object files* for the popular architectures (x86 being arguably the most mature). This is a relatively recent advance - prior to MC, LLVM had no functional assembler. Make sure to use the latest released LLVM version (which is currently 3.0 but will very soon be 3.1).

At this point LLVM's capabilities stop. You'll then need a platform linker to actually link the object file(s) into an executable. For example, `ld` is used on Linux-y platforms.

Note that this is true for today (April 2012), but unlikely to be true in the future. The LLD (LLVM Linker) project is now in early stages and aims to provide an LLVM-based linker that will jump the extra step required to produce fully loadable executables (and shared libraries) directly with LLVM tools, without relying on external tools.